# run azure function or webjob on-premises, but run only once

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

My scenario is I will want an azure function/webjob to stand by, the request won't ask it to run directly, but will set up a time to run, when it comes to that moment, it will run. Every request may want to run at different time. Is this possible on Azure function or webjob? or I have to implement this scheduler myself.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: A timer azure function runs on a schedule base, what I am hoping is I can schedule any moment to run this azure function once. E.g. request1: "run this azure function once at 5/10/2019 5AM", request 2: "run this azure function once at 5/9/2019 4AM". Is there this kind of trigger, or I have to write this scheduler module myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using either an Azure Storage Queue triggered or an Azure Service Bus triggered function for your scheduled functionality.

The scheduler function would be a HTTP triggered function which parses the payload and schedules a message into a storage queue or service bus queue.

> **Note** that the following details are for C#. For other languages, you will have to use the appropriate SDK instead of the bindings.

- **Storage Queues**
  You will have to set the `initialVisibilityDelay` parameter while adding a message using the [`CloudQueue.AddMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage?view=azure-dotnet) method.

  You will have to use the [queue storage output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#output---usage) to a CloudQueue object.
- **Service Bus**
  You can use the [Scheduled Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing#scheduled-messages) feature by setting [`Message.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.scheduledenqueuetimeutc?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_Message_ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc).

  You will have to use the [service bus output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output---usage) to a Message object.